# How to enable guests to join a captive portal in a new local network?

Tags: python-3, captive-portal

I am reading online tutorials about setting up captive portals for my raspberry pi using python, they all require an active internet connection to setup.

My question is: If I setup the Pi in my own home network to launch a captive portal and then give this raspberry pi to my friend, will they be able to find it on their local network and log in via the captive portal to give the Pi access to the internet using their own local network?

If so, do I need to setup it up in a specific way? All online tutorials mention setting it up in a home network, but haven't seen one that explains what happens when the Pi leaves that network.

I'd appreciate a guide on how to achieve this using Rasberry Pi and Python

Comment: why did you use a python tag?

Comment: why do you ask only simple yes/no questions?